# MQTT Telegraf - Filter by topic / fields doesn't work

Tags: mqtt, telegraf

I have a MQTT broker who send messages to InfluxDb using teletraf.
Mydevice send messages on 2 topics:

- srv/sensor1/tm
- srv/sensor2/attr/configuration

The messages are not same, i want to configure telegraf for send one on "M1" measurement and the second on "M2" measurement.
But the "topics" parameter seems not have effects.

Also, i set the "fields" parameter, but what i put in the fields, all json is stored in influx.

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://cfdsfapp.azure.com"]
  topics = [ "srv/+/attr/#" ]
  name_override = "M1"
  username = "teletr"
  password = "*******"
  data_format = "json"
  json_string_fields = ["sys_vbat@2","sys_vin@2","sys_batpct@2","pm_..."]
  json_time_key = "ts"
  json_time_format = "unix"
```

how can i make for the fields anf topic are restrictive ?